# Hybris sync system error

Tags: synchronization, sap-commerce-cloud

I am using the Hybris CMS system. I have recently uploaded multiple products through the productcockpit but when I go to sync on HMC I get "SYSTEM ERROR".

I'm trying to find the cause for the error, I have checked all the new products I have added but can't see anything wrong.

Here is the log file:

```
15.02.04 12:08:21:545   INFO    Starting configuration ...
15.02.04 12:08:23:607   INFO    Sync  'sync -ProductCatalog:Staged->Online' (pk:8796814049780) configured 8 entries for job '00002J68' (pk:8799964922357) schedule medias: 1
15.02.04 12:08:23:608   INFO    Finished configuration in 0d 00h:00m:02s:063ms.
15.02.04 12:08:23:608   INFO    Starting synchronization ...
15.02.04 12:08:29:082   INFO    1. pass, 7 (+7) of 8 items processed (87 %),  1,28 items/sec, 4 (+4) items dumped.
15.02.04 12:08:29:304   INFO    2. pass, 3 (+4) of 4 items processed (75 %),  18,02 items/sec, 4 (+4) items dumped.
15.02.04 12:08:29:369   INFO    comparing last dumps (4/8833109262366 vs 4/8833109360670) - this might take some time...
15.02.04 12:08:29:370   INFO    done comparing last dumps - dumps are equal
15.02.04 12:08:29:374   WARN    sync ended with 4 unfinished items - see last sync media for details
15.02.04 12:08:29:374   WARN    Finished synchronization in 0d 00h:00m:05s:766ms. There were errors during the synchronization!
```

Is it possible to find out what exactly is causing the error?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Most of the time sync issue is coming due to duplicate records. If is it you can find duplicate products in catalog -> Catalog Management Tools -> Duplicate Identifiers and remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the info on dropped lines in the output of the CronJob.

Go to the hMC > System > CronJobs. Find the CronJob 00002J68. Then you can download the unresolved lines CSV.

Comment: Just to clarify is the csv's with unresolved lines under the "administration" tab? I looked at them and it says:
`8797469573121;8797476945921;8799706940011;productBanners`

The numbers are the syncs but is there anyway to find out exactly what product's product banner is incorrect as quite a lot of products were changed.

Comment: Just to add to this, I can see unresolved csv's with useful information for imports but not for syncs (where we are having the issues).

Answer (score 2):

You can find dropped lines in CSV under HMC->System->CronJobs.

In output it will show pk of all components which caused the issue.

You can check pk by HAC->Platform->pk analyzer which will tell you place of PK, then, make Flexi Search for pk in table returned from pk analyzer. Hope that resolves the issue.